# Modifying an OOT block in GNU radio

Tags: gnu, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I have an existing and functioning OOT block in GNU radio. I am just trying to add an extra parameter to it to increase the block's flexibility.

I have made appropriate modifications in all the .h, .cc files corresponding to the block as well as the .cxx and swig.py. While executing the block, I still get an error saying 'RuntimeError: More keyword list entries (7) than format specifiers (6)' Im unable to find why. Is there an online resource apart from GNU tutorial which can guide me.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm going to assume version 3.7 because you mentioned swig.
The out of tree block is drawn according to the xml file in the grc folder.
Did you update the function calls in the xml to match your updates in the .h?